# ansible *servergroup* -m win_ping throws error

Tags: ssh, ansible, openssh

I installed and configured ansible as per the instructions on the official documentation. The setup is as follows:

WIN 10 Enterprise VM Host runs the ansible control node which is
Ubuntu 20.04LTS VM in VirtualBox.
This control node then SSHs to a Linux server (this works just fine) or a Windows Server 2019.

As mentioned before the connection has to happen via SSH and not winrm.
After the setup yesterday I was able to win_ping the server.  After that I changed the standard shell from cmd to PowerShell. win_pinged again and shut the VM off.

Today no changes whatsoever, I started the VM and for starters wanted to verify the connection and got an error back:

```
ansiblenode@ansiblenode-VirtualBox:~$ ansible windows-servers -m win_ping
```

```js
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The TRANSFORM_INVALID_GROUP_CHARS settings is set to allow bad characters in group names by default, this will 
change, but still be user configurable on deprecation. This feature will be removed in version 2.10. Deprecation warnings can be 
disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details
windowsTest_host1 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "At line:1 char:26\r\n+ chcp.com 65001 >nul 2>&1 && PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Ex ...\r\n+                          ~~\r\nThe token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine\r\n \r\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Detailed Version with -vvvv:

```js
windowsTest_host1 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname XXX.XX.XXX.XXX is address\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/home/ansiblenode/.ansible/cp/c7e43effac\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct\r\ndebug1: Connecting to XXX.XX.XXX.XXX [XXX.XX.XXX.XXX] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Connection established.\r\ndebug3: timeout: 9980 ms remain after connect\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_rsa type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_dsa type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_xmss type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4\r\ndebug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6\r\ndebug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Authenticating to XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:22 as 'Administrator'\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/home/ansiblenode/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/known_hosts:1\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from XXX.XX.XXX.XXX\r\ndebug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received\r\ndebug2: local client KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256\r\ndebug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256\r\ndebug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 30\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 31\r\ndebug1: Server host key: XXXXXXXXXX
 hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/home/ansiblenode/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/known_hosts:1\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from XXX.XX.XXX.XXX\r\ndebug1: Host 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.\r\ndebug1: Found key in /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/known_hosts:1\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 1\r\ndebug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 21\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 0\r\ndebug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_rsa \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_dsa \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ecdsa \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ed25519 \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_xmss \r\ndebug2: pubkey_prepare: done\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 5\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 7\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received\r\ndebug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 6\r\ndebug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive\r\ndebug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive\r\ndebug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup publickey\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: publickey\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_rsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_dsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ecdsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ed25519\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_xmss\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/ansiblenode/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: password\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive\r\ndebug2: userauth_kbdint\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive\r\ndebug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup password\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: \r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled password\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: password\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 52\r\ndebug1: Enabling compression at level 6.\r\ndebug1: Authentication succeeded (password).\r\nAuthenticated to XXX.XX.XXX.XXX ([XXX.XX.XXX.XXX]:22).\r\ndebug1: setting up multiplex master socket\r\ndebug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /home/ansiblenode/.ansible/cp/c7e43effac.bc3nbpSV394EBUJr\r\ndebug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: channel 0: new [/home/ansiblenode/.ansible/cp/c7e43effac]\r\ndebug3: muxserver_listen: mux listener channel 0 fd 4\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY\r\ndebug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08\r\ndebug1: control_persist_detach: backgrounding master process\r\ndebug2: control_persist_detach: background process is 3177\r\ndebug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: forking to background\r\ndebug1: Entering interactive session.\r\ndebug1: pledge: id\r\ndebug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: schedule exit in 60 seconds\r\ndebug1: multiplexing control connection\r\ndebug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: channel 1: new [mux-control]\r\ndebug3: channel_post_mux_listener: new mux channel 1 fd 5\r\ndebug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1: hello sent\r\ndebug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: cancel scheduled exit\r\ndebug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x00000001 len 4\r\ndebug2: mux_master_process_hello: channel 1 slave version 4\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x10000004 len 4\r\ndebug2: mux_master_process_alive_check: channel 1: alive check\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 3179\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x10000002 len 3122\r\ndebug2: mux_master_process_new_session: channel 1: request tty 0, X 0, agent 0, subsys 0, term \"xterm-256color\", cmd \"chcp.com 65001 >nul 2>&1 && PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -EncodedCommand UABvAHcAZQByAFMAaABlAGwAbAAgAC0ATgBvAFAAcgBvAGYAaQBsAGUAIAAtAE4AbwBuAEkAbgB0AGUAcgBhAGMAdABpAHYAZQAgAC0ARQB4AGUAYwB1AHQAaQBvAG4AUABvAGwAaQBjAHkAIABVAG4AcgBlAHMAdAByAGkAYwB0AGUAZAAgAC0ARQBuAGMAbwBkAGUAZABDAG8AbQBtAGEAbgBkACAASgBnAEIAagBBAEcAZwBBAFkAdwBCAHcAQQBDADQAQQBZAHcAQgB2AEEARwAwAEEASQBBAEEAMgBBAEQAVQBBAE0AQQBBAHcAQQBEAEUAQQBJAEEAQQArAEEAQwBBAEEASgBBAEIAdQBBAEgAVQBBAGIAQQBCAHMAQQBBAG8AQQBKAEEAQgBsAEEASABnAEEAWgBRAEIAagBBAEYAOABBAGQAdwBCAHkAQQBHAEUAQQBjAEEAQgB3AEEARwBVAEEAYwBnAEIAZgBBAEgATQBBAGQAQQBCAHkAQQBDAEEAQQBQAFEAQQBnAEEAQwBRAEEAYQBRAEIAdQBBAEgAQQBBAGQAUQBCADAAQQBDAEEAQQBmAEEAQQBnAEEARQA4AEEAZABRAEIAMABBAEMAMABBAFUAdwBCADAAQQBIAEkAQQBhAFEAQgB1AEEARwBjAEEAQwBnAEEAawBBAEgATQBBAGMAQQBCAHMAQQBHAGsAQQBkAEEAQgBmAEEASABBAEEAWQBRAEIAeQBBAEgAUQBBAGMAdwBBAGcAQQBEADAAQQBJAEEAQQBrAEE\r\ndebug3: mux_master_process_new_session: got fds stdin 6, stdout 7, stderr 8\r\ndebug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: channel 2: new [client-session]\r\ndebug2: mux_master_process_new_session: channel_new: 2 linked to control channel 1\r\ndebug2: channel 2: send open\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 90\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 80\r\ndebug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 91\r\ndebug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 2: callback start\r\ndebug2: client_session2_setup: id 2\r\ndebug1: Sending environment.\r\ndebug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = de_DE.UTF-8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: Sending env LC_NAME = de_DE.UTF-8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = de_DE.UTF-8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = de_DE.UTF-8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = de_DE.UTF-8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = de_DE.UTF-8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = de_DE.UTF-8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: Sending env LC_TIME = de_DE.UTF-8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = de_DE.UTF-8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request env confirm 0\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: Sending command: chcp.com 65001 >nul 2>&1 && PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -EncodedCommand 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\r\ndebug2: channel 2: request exec confirm 1\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug3: mux_session_confirm: sending success reply\r\ndebug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 2: callback done\r\ndebug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd adjust 2097152\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 99\r\ndebug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2\r\ndebug2: exec request accepted on channel 2\r\ndebug2: channel 2: read<=0 rfd 6 len 0\r\ndebug2: channel 2: read failed\r\ndebug2: channel 2: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 6 efd 8 [write])\r\ndebug2: channel 2: input open -> drain\r\ndebug2: channel 2: ibuf empty\r\ndebug2: channel 2: send eof\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 96\r\ndebug2: channel 2: input drain -> closed\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd adjust 16384\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd ext data 19\r\nAt line:1 char:26\r\ndebug2: channel 2: written 19 to efd 8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd ext data 77\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd ext data 31\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd ext data 68\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd ext data 87\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd ext data 48\r\n+ chcp.com 65001 >nul 2>&1 && PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Ex ...\r\n+                          ~~\r\nThe token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine\r\ndebug2: channel 2: written 311 to efd 8\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd ext data 3\r\n \r\ndebug2: channel 2: written 3 to efd 8\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd eow\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 96\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd eof\r\ndebug2: channel 2: output open -> drain\r\ndebug2: channel 2: obuf empty\r\ndebug2: channel 2: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 7 efd 8 [write])\r\ndebug2: channel 2: output drain -> closed\r\ndebug2: channel 2: send close\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 97\r\ndebug3: channel 2: will not send data after close\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype exit-status reply 0\r\ndebug3: mux_exit_message: channel 2: exit message, exitval 1\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 97\r\ndebug2: channel 2: rcvd close\r\ndebug3: channel 2: will not send data after close\r\ndebug2: channel 2: is dead\r\ndebug2: channel 2: gc: notify user\r\ndebug3: mux_master_session_cleanup_cb: entering for channel 2\r\ndebug2: channel 1: rcvd close\r\ndebug2: channel 1: output open -> drain\r\ndebug2: channel 1: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o1 sock 5 wfd 5 efd -1 [closed])\r\ndebug2: channel 1: input open -> closed\r\ndebug2: channel 2: gc: user detached\r\ndebug2: channel 2: is dead\r\ndebug2: channel 2: garbage collecting\r\ndebug1: channel 2: free: client-session, nchannels 3\r\ndebug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:\r\n  #1 mux-control (t16 nr0 i3/0 o1/16 e[closed]/0 fd 5/5/-1 sock 5 cc -1)\r\n  #2 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/8 sock -1 cc -1)\r\n\r\ndebug2: channel 1: obuf empty\r\ndebug2: channel 1: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock 5 wfd 5 efd -1 [closed])\r\ndebug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed\r\ndebug2: channel 1: is dead (local)\r\ndebug2: channel 1: gc: notify user\r\ndebug3: mux_master_control_cleanup_cb: entering for channel 1\r\ndebug2: channel 1: gc: user detached\r\ndebug2: channel 1: is dead (local)\r\ndebug2: channel 1: garbage collecting\r\ndebug1: channel 1: free: mux-control, nchannels 2\r\ndebug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:\r\n  #1 mux-control (t16 nr0 i3/0 o3/0 e[closed]/0 fd 5/5/-1 sock 5 cc -1)\r\n\r\ndebug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: schedule exit in 60 seconds\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 1\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

Does sbdy know where these errors are coming from?
The error the that's actually thrown is even larger than what I posted in the second codesnippet. For some reason it won't paste the full version though.
(Maybe I do have to change the language from JS, but to what I don't know)

Thanks for you're help.

EDIT1:

I did find that line in the logs:

```
<XXX.XX.XXX.XXX> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d11 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="Administrator"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ansiblenode/.ansible/cp/c7e43effac XXX.XX.XXX.XXX 'chcp.com 65001 >nul 2>&1 && PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -EncodedCommand

 Failed to connect to the host via ssh: At line:1 char:26 + chcp.com 65001 >nul 2>&1 && PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Ex ...
```

This appears to be what the error is pointing to, but I lack the knowledge to know where to find and how to change and to what value.

EDIT2:
As far as I understand it has something to do with cmd vs PowerShell Commands.
Maybe there is something to change in addition to what is outlined in the officle ansible docs.

I was under the impression that when working with ansible one should change the default shell to PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that for previous reasons I had specified the

```
ansible_shell_type=cmd
```

in the hosts file for windows-servers

```
ansible_shell_type=powershell
```

now works just fine.

Maybe would've gotten to the solution faster if I didn't convince myself that I had done another thestrun after changing the default shell to powershell.

Maybe it helps someone else to remember to check their hosts file.